# Most effective and elegant way to check parameters using if conditons

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have 3 parameters to check with some conditions.

As an example my code as follows,

```
    public static string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
    {
        var response = "";

        if (msg == "hello" && score >= 20 && age <= 25)
        {
            response = "All para success";
        }
        if (msg != "hello" && score >= 20 && age <= 25)
        {
            response = "Unmatching message";
        }
        if (msg == "hello" && score < 20 && age <= 25)
        {
            response = "Score not satisfied";
        }
        if (msg == "hello" && score >= 20 && age > 25)
        {
            response = "Age not satisfied";
        }
        if (msg != "hello" && score < 20 && age <= 25)
        {
            response = "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied ";
        }
        if (msg != "hello" && score >= 20 && age > 25)
        {
            response = "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied";
        }
        if (msg == "hello" && score < 20 && age > 25)
        {
            response = "Age & Score not satisfied";
        }
        if (msg != "hello" && score < 20 && age > 25)
        {
            response = "All parameter unsatisfied";
        }
        return response;
    }}
```

There have 3 parameters and 8 probability can happen based on its values. Here I check those as above code. But it looks ugly and I think it's not the best way to do this. what is most efficient and elegant way to do this

Comment: You could test the 3 conditions by themselves and then aggregate the results. But there is no "nice" way existing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem to solve rather it is inviting _code review_.  It may be relevant on another Stack Exchange site

Comment: @Sachith Don't get distracted by downvotes. Downvotes are anonymous, and complaining about it will just get more downvotes. Update your question to be clearer, and the upvotes will come.

Comment: It’s probably not that much different.   What other ways have you tried?   Any research?   As for the other site it may be something you could ask on Code Review but I’m no expert.  Be sure you check out their guidelines and faq before you post.  Good luck

Answer (score 3):

what about grouping it first like so:

```
public string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
{
   var response = "";

   if (msg == "hello") {
       response = score > 20 ? 
        age > 25 ? "Age not satisfied" : "All para success"
        : age < 25 ? "Score not satisfied" : "Age & Score not satisfied";       
   } else {
        if  (score > 20)
        {
            response = age < 25 ? "Unmatching message" : "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied" ;    

        } else {

            response = age < 25 ? "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied " : "All parameter unsatisfied" ;          
        }   
   }    
   return response;
 }
```

also you need to note condition if it is equal. for example

```
if (msg == "hello" && score > 20 && age < 25)
{
    response = "All para success";
}

//and ...
if (msg == "hello" && score < 20 && age < 25)
{
    response = "Score not satisfied";
}
// what if score == 20 ?
```

with `if else` statement or `The conditional operator (?:)` we can avoid that

**Update**

```
if(msg == "hello")
{
    if(score < 20)
    {
        response = age > 25 ? "Age & Score not satisfied" : "Score not satisfied";
    } else {
        response = age > 25 ? "Age not satisfied" : "All para success";
    }
} else {
    if(score < 20)
    {
        response = age > 25 ? "All parameter unsatisfied" : "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied ";
    } else {
        response = age > 25 ? "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied" : "Unmatching message";     
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely more compact, but just become a lot harder to read. anyway upvote for fulling the requirement of the question

Comment: @RizkiDPrast Its good, But what about this? `Age & Score not satisfied`

Comment: updated on line `: age < 25 ? "Score not satisfied" : "Age & Score not satisfied";` yaa a bit harder to read though :p

Comment: @RizkiDPrast you are correct I missed that part, I mean when score = 20 and age = 25. I updated my question. what should I need to change in your code to satisfy updated code

Answer (score 3):

```
            List<String> Errors = new List<String>();
            int chk = 3;
            if ( msg != "hello" )
            {
                Errors.Add( "Unmatching message" );
            }
            if ( score < 20 )
            {
                Errors.Add( "Score not satisfied" );
            }
            if ( age > 25 )
            {
                Errors.Add( "Age not satisfied" );
            }

            if ( Errors.Count == 0 )
            {
                return "All para success";
            }
            else if ( Errors.Count == 3)
            {
                return "All parameter unsatisfied";
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Join( " & ", Errors );
            }
```

** Code edited because I mis-typed String.Join as String.Format **

or you can also use byte for this if you want to make case by case answers

```
            int flag = 0x0;
            if ( msg == "hello" )
            {
                flag |= 0x1;
            }
            if ( score > 20 )
            {
                flag |= 0x2;
            }
            if ( age < 25 )
            {
                flag |= 0x4;
            }
            switch ( flag )
            {
                case 0x7:
                    response = "All para success";
                    break;
                case 0x6:
                    response = "Unmatching message";
                    break;
                case 0x5:
                    response = "Score not satisfied";
                    break;
                case 0x4:
                    response = "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied";
                    break;
                case 0x3:
                    response = "Score not satisfied";
                    break;
                case 0x2:
                    response = "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied ";
                    break;
                case 0x1:
                    response = "Score not satisfied & Age not satisfied";
                    break;
                default:
                    response = "All parameter unsatisfied";
                    break;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private const string MESSAGE = "hello";
    private const int SCORE = 20;
    private const int AGE = 25;
    public string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
    {
        if (msg == MESSAGE)
        {
            if (score > SCORE)
            {
                return age < AGE ? "All para success" : "Age not satisfied";
            }
            else
            {
                return age < AGE ? "Score not satisfied" : "Age & Score not satisfied";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (score > SCORE)
            {
                return age < AGE ? "Unmatching message" : "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied";
            }
            else
            {
                return age < AGE ? "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied " : "All parameter unsatisfied";
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This looks the most sensible so far (for what it is)

Comment: The first `else` should be removed - it will never be entered.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to create dictionary, which contains your truth table and corresponding response, for example:

```
private readonly Dictionary<(bool isMsgValid, bool isScoreValid, bool isAgeValid), string> _responses 
    = new Dictionary<(bool, bool, bool), string>()
{
    [(true, true, true)] = "All para success",
    [(false, false, false)] = "All parameter unsatisfied",
    [(false, true, true)] = "Unmatching message",
    [(true, false, true)] = "Score not satisfied",
    [(true, true, false)] = "Age not satisfied",
    [(false, false, true)] = "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied",
    [(false, true, false)] = "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied",
    [(true, false, false)] = "Age & Score not satisfied"
};

public string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
    => _responses[(msg == "hello", score > 20, age < 25)];
```

It's up to you to decide which variant is more elegant, this is just one of the possible solution.

Note, that here's using [C# 7.0 features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/), ValueTuple at the dictionary keys, and expression bodied method `checkIfConnditions`.

**EDIT**

Here is the example, which I have been used for testing:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<(bool isMsgValid, bool isScoreValid, bool isAgeValid), string> _responses 
        = new Dictionary<(bool, bool, bool), string>()
    {
        [(true, true, true)] = "All para success",
        [(false, false, false)] = "All parameter unsatisfied",
        [(false, true, true)] = "Unmatching message",
        [(true, false, true)] = "Score not satisfied",
        [(true, true, false)] = "Age not satisfied",
        [(false, false, true)] = "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied",
        [(false, true, false)] = "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied",
        [(true, false, false)] = "Age & Score not satisfied"
    };

    public static string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
        => _responses[(msg == "hello", score > 20, age < 25)];

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("hello", 45, 20));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("hello", 45, 30));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("hello", 10, 20));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("hello", 10, 30));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("goodbye", 45, 20));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("goodbye", 10, 30));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("goodbye", 45, 20));
        Console.WriteLine(checkIfConnditions("goodbye", 10, 30));
    }
}
```

Note, that `_responses` and `checkIfConnditions` must be static in that case.

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with this :( can you post your tried example here. That 'll  be more understandable to me

Comment: Of course, added the example of usage, which checks all 8 solutions.

Comment: I tested this, and after updating you I copy pasted this, but errors occurred in the dictionary

Comment: Make sure that you have at least C# 7.0 version selected, [here's guide how to select new version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  Sometimes these long "if's" can get a little messy.
> ```

```
        public string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            if (msg == "hello")
            {
                if (score > 20 && age < 25)
                    response = "All para success";
                else if (score < 20 && age < 25)
                    response = "Score not satisfied";
                else if (score > 20 && age > 25)
                    response = "Age not satisfied";
                else if ( score < 20 && age > 25)     // Corrected this line
                    response = "Age & Score not satisfied";
            }
            else
            {
                if (score < 20 && age < 25)
                    response = "Unmatiching message & Score not satisfied ";
                else if (score > 20 && age > 25)
                    response = "Unmatiching message & Age not satisfied";
                else if (score > 20 && age < 25)
                    response = "Unmatching message";
                else if (score < 20 && age > 25)
                    response = "All parameter unsatisfied";
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would concatenate the results:

```
public string checkIfConnditions(string msg, int score, int age)
{
    List<String> msgList = List<String>();    
    if (msg != "hello")
        msgList.add("Message");

    if (score < 20)
        msgList.add("Score");

    if (age > 25)
        msgList.add("Age");

    var response = "All para success"
    for(int i=0;i<msgList.Count;i++)
    {
         if(i=0) 
             response = msgList[i] 
         else 
             response += " & "+ msgList[i] 

         if(i==msgList.Count-1)
             response += " not satisfied"
    }

    return response;
```